# What are some Outlook plugins/add-ins that take the invitees of a meeting and add them to the body of an invite?

Tags: calendar, outlook

I would like to automatically, or at the press of 1 or 2 clicks/buttons, insert the list of invitees of my meeting into my invite in Outlook, at meeting creation time.

I have seen this done once before and thought it was a great idea. I have been able to replicate this invitee list, but only by manually copying/pasting. I have not been able to find any add-ins or plugins (they're different words for the same thing as far as Outlook is concerned) that claim to do this. I've actually been having a hard time find add-ins in general.

Are there any add-ins that do what I am looking for? Perhaps something close?

What are some reputable places to find Outlook add-ins without catching some ITDs? (Internet Transmitted Diseases)?

I have Outlook 2013 connected to an on-prem Exchange environment, if that matters for the add-ins.

Comment: Regarding your edits undoing my edits: (1) As this is a beta site, the help topics are not really useful yet; the scope gets discussed on our [Meta] site, where you can find, for example: [Can I ask for recommended websites?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/191/). We want to recommend *software* here, not *sites* that list/offer/recommend software. (2) I think my edit to the title made it shorter, fixed the case,  and removed the implication that *several* solutions should be *listed*, while actually a *single* recommended solution would suffice (right?).

Comment: I poked around the meta site a bit too and found some rather lengthy discussion about the philosophy of asking questions about software recommendations.  Eventually I found out there's a sister site where you can ask about we apps, but not actual software.  I'm new to Stack Exchange and the more I engage with it, the more I'm not entirely sure the purpose.  In short, it's more like a convoluted wall of "no, go away" than a site geared towards finding help or answers, though I understand the general philosophy of moderating help vampires and teaching people to find information on their own.